# Skewed teradata Join (Spool space problems)

Tags: sql, join, teradata

I'm trying to optimize a join between two tables with different PIs

- Customer Table: Indexed by an Customer Surrogate Key (CUSTOMER_SK)
- Account Table: Indexed by an Account Surrogate Key (ACCOUNT_SK)

The Account table has a conceptual foreign key (Conceptual because it's not enforced by the table declarion) that references the customer owner of the account (CUSTOMER_FK). A customer can have more than one account, but each account has only one customer.

I'm trying to bring an attribute from the Customer to the Account, for posterior processing of business rules. Currently, i'm joining the two tables using the following steps:

1- Extract a subset (filter on the table) by information reference date, and reindexing the results by the Customer Foreign Key. That way, both tables are distributed by the same keys over the AMPs

2- Join the tables on the Customer Key on both tables (CUSTOMER_SK and CUSTOMER_FK), reindexing the results on ACCOUNT_SK.

Thing is, I have a few clientes (< 10) that have millions of accounts. Because of this, the reindexed account table is terribly skewed. The skew factor of the original table (Indexed over the Account Surrogate) is 1, against 98 on the reindexed table, and I'm frequently running out of Spool Space (Even when the query gets to run, it impact the server overall performance)

Is there any way to optimize this query?

Edit:

I can't post the exact query due to information security policies of my employer (I could only get clearance for sharing the problem on a generic form)

Comment: Edit your question and show the query.  There's not much that can be said about optimizing a query that isn't included in the question.

Comment: I can't post the exact query due to information security policies of my employer (I could only get clearance for sharing the problem on a generic form)

Comment: Why do step 1? You are trading index for a terrible sku. I would rather have it process across all amps then have a nice index. It seems like a combination of stats collection and an AJI holding the join between your two tables would be a better route (although it's hard to say without seeing the query and all that). Maybe as a first step try a secondary index on the customer foreign key for both tables? It won't affect distribution, but it should help so you don't have to have an intermediate table with bad skew.

Comment: Also you noted in step 1 that you pull by a "Reference Date". Could you pull month and year off of that and use that as a partition, or would that not make sense for your query?

Comment: What's your Teradata release? 14.10 introduced the "partial redistribution partial duplication" optimization (aka "ebay-join") for exactly this scenario. Are there statistics on the join columns?

Comment: @dnoeth, the Partial Redistribution Partial Duplication did the trick! If you could post this as an answer I will accept it.